# Spring JPA NULL not allowed when inserting join table entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the table structure

**SELLER**

> | ID |

**CUSTOMER**

> | ID |

**Transaction**

> | ID | SELLER_ID | CUSTOMER_ID |

And I represent these by entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SELLER")
public class Seller {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "seller", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Transaction> transactions;

}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Transaction> transactions;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSACTION")
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "SELLER_ID",
            insertable = false,
            updatable = false,
            nullable = false,
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "TRA_SLR_FK")
    )
    private Seller seller;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "CUSTOMER_ID",
            insertable = false,
            updatable = false,
            nullable = false,
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "TRA_CMR_FK")
    )
    private Customer customer;

}
```

---

When I try to create a Transaction and save it using a CrudRepository:

```
public interface TransactionRepository extends CrudRepository<Transaction,Long> {}
```

Using:

```
Customer customer = customerRepository.findOne(1L); // Similar CrudRepository    
Seller seller = sellerRepository.findOne(1L); // Similar CrudRepository    
Transaction transaction = new Transaction(seller, customer);
transaction = transactionRepository.save(transaction);
```

I get the error:

> NULL not allowed for column "CUSTOMER_ID"; SQL statement: insert into
>   transaction (id) values (null) [23502-195]

Why is it not using the `customer` to populate the `CUSTOMER_ID` when I call `save`?

Comment: Did you retrive customer with a query or something, or you are creating a new customer ?

Comment: Retrieved with a query, I'll add that for clarity

Comment: According to https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html, i think you should not mark your join columns with insertable=false, this is making that the object is not included on sql insert generation, if don't missunderstand the javadoc xD

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#insertable(), tell us if it works

Comment: @karelss That worked thank you! I always assumed the insertable in the Transaction entity meant "Transactions cannot inser Sellers/Customers"

Comment: you are not the first neither the last xDD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html), properties like insertable, updateable refers to SQL generation, not to insert or update related entities.